# Postman 400 Bad Request for web Api

Tags: http, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a very basic webApi built/running (pretty much template app, nothing more) in order to follow a training video.  The GET and DELETE calls work fine, PUT and POST give a 400 error.  Admittedly very new to all this so I'm looking for some basic direction as to how to troubleshoot.  Pertinent screen shots follow, I'd be glad to provide others as requested.  Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: UPDATE:  Figured it out, I needed to use the "Raw" option in Postman, and provide the parameter value in quotes, I'd been using a non-quoted value or kvp etc., that wasn't able to be properly formatted as json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are trying to make POST request which needs string value in its body.

Step to the Body section of the Postman Request, select `form-data` after that add `value` as parameterName and `This is test string` as parameter value

[image]

Comment: I have tried manipulating the Body, and have tried "none", "form-data", "x-www-form-urlencoded", etc., they all still return the 400.  and thanks for such a quick response!

Comment: you need to use form-data, others are not relevant.

Comment: I need you to try one more thing. Select Raw and just write a text in it. then send it

Comment: Have tried that one too, but here is the latest test using Raw:  POST /api/values HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:53091
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: b62d712a-d361-434d-808a-88f6688aad3b
test------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, commenting out the "[FromBody] string value" parm in the api code will allow the call to go through and my breakpoint is hit on the Post method.

Comment: If your breakpoint hit on debug, It means that you succesfully called your method. Yet your method does not have any return value. Put `return Created()` for testing and change return type of your method to IActionResult

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider to mark it as answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187449/discussion-between-mike-and-simonare).

Answer (score 0):

I know this very old thread but may help someone so posting my answer.
try updating your method attribute[HttpPost("New")]  and call it as http:localhost//api/new.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is a development env on .net core.

This drove me nuts and lost 5 hours, all preventing post requests from either the browser calls or from Postman.

The following three changes helped me in 3 different scenarios.

1. First I disabled the https and made it only http. Commented out sslPort and removed 's' from https.

[image: launch url in application settings json file]

2. Next I felt xsrf/csrf token are causing issues, so I disabled Anti Forgery token as follows. As you can see I applied the IgnoreAntiforgeryToken attribute at the controller level, but you may also apply at the action method level as needed. The token is sent anyway, but you can ask .net core to ignore it, for that route.

[image: Applying anti forgery token at controller level]

3. Finally, I noticed that ApiVersion parameter in the action method is also causing issues, so I commented that out as well.

[image: ApiVersion parameter with FromRoute attribute]

Comment: Removing the attribute [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] above from the API method fixed my issue. Is that the right approch?